# OPC-UA: Certificate signed by (self-issued) CA return NULL without error messages, what am i missing?

Tags: c++, ssl, certificate, opc-ua

I'm trying to create a certificate-creator using OPC-UA clientsdk tools (which uses openssl intern). While creating simple certs and CA-certs is no problem and easy to handle, creating a cert-chain doesn't work. If I'm trying to create a derived cert, the cert returned is NULL.
For all those versions I use the same method, the only difference is the UaPkiCertificate constructor. I searched the entire internet if someone had a similar problem, but I found nothing.
Here is the code:

```
UaPkiCertificate cert;
if( CA_cert )
{
    cert = UaPkiCertificate(
        info,
        identity,
        keys,
        true );
}
else
{
    UaPkiCertificate validator = UaPkiCertificate::fromDERFile( "cert_NAME.der" );
    UaPkiPrivateKey val_key = UaPkiRsaKeyPair::fromPEMFile( "keys_NAME.pem", "password" ).privateKey();
    cert = UaPkiCertificate(
        info,
        identity,
        keys.publicKey(),
        validator,
        val_key,
        false,
        UaPkiCertificate::SignatureAlgorithm_Sha256
    );
}
```

Am I missing something obvios?
getErrors() does return an empty list, so it's no help.
I also tested if the inputs(keys and certs) are correctly loaded, which they are.

Comment: i won't be able to answer comments for the next 90 minutes, so please be patient if you have questions.

Comment: It seems you are using an OPC UA SDK from Unified Automation. Please contact them for support or use their own Forum: https://www.unified-automation.com/support.html

Comment: Your right, that would be smart. But i think i already figured it out, because even though the keys seem to be loaded (as the function calls note no problems whatsoever), they actually aren't. Think this is a an easier problem.